# ESP32 CAM - EEPROM / sdcard / non erasable memory - beginner problem

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, esp32, eeprom

**Overwiew**

I am working on my first project with ESP32, I have ESP32 CAM model and I am creating an automatic roller blinds. I got most of the project working - I have web server that controls continous servo and all mechanics. I want to be able to adjust the time for going up-down without reprograming the microcontroller. The goal is to have an automatic roller blinds with alarm clock function.

**Problem**

I need a way to reliable save/read data to store variables state, even without power. How to achive it with ESP32 CAM?

**Additional info**

On Arduino board that would be EEPROM, and I found some tutorials that claim that EEPROM can be used on ESP32. However, when I tried using EEPROM, it looks like the values are overwritten while bootloading. So I guess ESP32 CAM needs different approach. Correct me if I am wrong, please.

Comment: Arduino esp32 ?

Comment: No @Juraj - You clearly did not understood the question.

Comment: yes you use arduino-esp32 boards package. what is what I didn't understand? with esp32 IDF framework the answer would be different

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so user bvguy on Reddit solved my problem.

"EEPROM is deprecated. They want you to use preferences now. Here is an [example](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/Preferences/examples/StartCounter/StartCounter.ino) ."

I tested the example and it works on my ESP32 CAM, therfore solving the problem.